# SOAP UI Groovy Script error , "Cannot invoke method readLine()"

Tags: groovy, soapui

Error thrown"java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method readLine() on null object error at Line 1" when below groovy script is run on
SOAP UI Version 5.1.3

```
nextLine = context.fileReader.readLine()
if(nextLine != null){
String[] propData = nextLine.split(",") 
curTC = testRunner.testCase
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear, `context.fileReader` is null because there is no property `fileReader` inside `context`, this is why you get the `NPE` when you invoke `readLine()` on it.

To use `context.fileReader`, first you've to set something in the property, for example in your case:

```
context.fileReader = new FileReader("/myTempFile.txt")
def nextLine = context.fileReader.readLine()
if(nextLine != null){
String[] propData = nextLine.split(",") 
curTC = testRunner.testCase
```

This example has non sense at all, it's only illustrative; normally `context` in SOAPUI is used to pass different objects from one testStep to another inside a TestCase execution, or from one TestCase to another inside a TestSuite etc...

For example you have a TestCase and want to pass a property through different testSteps, in one TestStep you set the property as:

```
context.fileReader = new FileReader("/myTempFile.txt")
```

And then in another TestStep you get it back to use it as:

```
def nextLine = context.fileReader.readLine()
```

Hope this helps,